# iPhone keyboard appearace magically changes

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I have an iPhone iOS 7 app with 2 entry fields, Username and Password.  The Username field ALWAYS has a Dark Appearance, whereas the Password field ALWAYS has a Light Appearance.  This occurs even though I set the keyboardAppearance to a specific Light or Dark Appearance, both through Interface Builder and through code!

Any suggestions as to why or how to make it be consistent.  My client doesn't like the flakiness (nor do I), but he cares!

Comment: Is it possible for you to include a screenshot?

Comment: Maybe this could fix it? `[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];`

Comment: Could you include a link to the project, so that it is possible to play around and search for a solution?

Comment: a screenshot?  Hmmm, do you not understand difference between dark and light???

setKeyboardAppearance method did not change anything.  I was already using the keyboardAppearance property.

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

Was looking at the wrong XIB.  It had 'Dark' for one field and 'Default' of the other.